# What does `&` operator do to a standard logic vector?

Tags: vhdl

I'm looking at some code that does the following:

```
signal1 : std_logic
vector1 : std_logic_vector

vector1 <= vector1(20 downto 1) & signal1;
```

I assume that a `vector1(20 downto 1)` produces the following:

```
[20 19 18 ... 3 2 1]
```

but what I don't understand is what the `&` does to it.  Does it return a `0` if `signal1` is `0` and the vector created if `signal1` is `1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&` is not comparison : it's the concatenation operator. It builds a larger array (vector, string) out of smaller ones or components (bits, characters).

`vector1(20 downto 1)`  simply takes a 20 bit slice from `vector1` : `&` appends `signal1` to it, making a new 21 bit vector. This is then assigned by `<=` to `vector1`, which I assume must be 21 bits long (or you have a compile time error!)

If `vector1` is declared as

```
signal vector1 : std_logic_vector(21 downto 1);
```

then this is a shift register; every such operation is a left shift by 1 bit, with a new LSB from `signal1`.

Comment: Ah you're right.  It's actually a delay (I think).  It's something like this: `vector1 <= vector1(DelayVal downto 1) & signal1;` which would in essence delay `signal1` by the number of DelayVal clock cycles.

Comment: bingo : that's one common use for a shift register. For bonus points, vector1's length ought to be declared in terms of DelayVal.